# Is there any mathematical study about |a-b|=f(|g(a)-g(b)|)? or does there exist f() and g() satisfy this equation?

Tags: functional-equations

The problem is just as the title. It is clear that the linear function $f(x)=kx$ and $g(x)=(1/k)x$ can meet it. Is there any other function pairs f(x) and g(x) can meet this equation? or the equation $(a-b)^2=f((g(a)-g(b))^2)$?

Comment: You can add more restrictions and get something equivalent to Cauchy's functional equation. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation What does this have to do with algebraic geometry?

Comment: I read the Cauchy's functional equation. While its form may be an example with $f(x)=g^{-1}(x)$. Sorry about the category, I'm just a newcomer, have no idea to category this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me consider first a slightly different equation $|g(a)-g(b)|=f(|a-b|).$
There is no continuously differentiable function $g$ like this, except $g(x)=kx+c$.

Proof. Let $a=x$, $b=x+1$. Then we gave $g(x+1)-g(x)=\pm k,$ where $k=f(1)$, and this is
for every $x$. As $g$ is continuous there must be one sign for all $x$,
for example $g(x+1)-g(x)=k$. Differentiating we conclude that $g^{\prime}$ has period $1$. Repeating the same argument with $\sqrt{2}$ instead of $1$, we conclude that
$g^{\prime}$ has period $\sqrt{2}$. Therefore, $g^{\prime}$ must be constant.

The same argument applies to your equation if you assume that the sets $f^{-1}(c)$
do not contain intervals. Now, for the problem to make sense, $f$ must be surjective.
Therefore, for all $c$, except countably many, $f^{-1}(c)$ cannot contain an interval. Co you can find
two non-commensurable values $c'$ and $c"$ whose $f$-preimages do not contain intervals.
Then the previous argument shows that every $C^1$ solution $g$ must be
affine.

Your second equation is the same as the first one if you replace $f$ by $f_1(x)=\sqrt{f(x^2)}$.

On the other hand, if you put no restrictions on $g$ whatsoever, one can construct crazy examples using axiom of choice.

Comment: Already $g^\prime$ is periodic with period $1$ and $\sqrt{2}$, by your argument, and therefore constant. You don't need to differentiate twice.